# "Close" button on child WebBrowser window closes an parent one(.NET, winforms)

Tags: .net, winforms, embedded-browser

I'm using WebBrowser control to allow user navigate to intranet web-portal and keep user in c# desktop application. In some cases user can clicks on link on html-page and child window with WebBrowser control opens(to do that, I subscribed to NewWindow event on parent WebBrowser control).
There is "Close" button on child window's page. It like like that:
`<input type="button" name="closeButton" onclick="window.close()">`
When user clicks on this button window with parent BrowserControl closes(without rising close/closing events) and child window becomes hanging.

But if we do same steps in IE6 - everything works fine.
Any propositions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Erm, what does "becomes hanging" mean?  Post real repro code.

Comment: Window hangs: doesn't respond on mouse/keyboards events, doesn't allow moving, sizing, etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, problem was solved, but in a bit dirty way:  after opening popup window I find `"closeButton"` and  erase code in its `"onclick"` event and then I attach event handler to "`onclick`" event(api allows to do that), which contains code, that closes popup window through winforms api manually;

Comment: What's more, I've found great solution on Mauricio Rojas Blog http://blogs.artinsoft.net/mrojas/archive/2009/05/21/webbrowser-control-and-window-close.aspx . It solved all problems.